# SQL Server traverse parent until match in connected table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables:

```
Unit
===============
Id (pk),
ParentId (fk same table),
Name

UnitManager
===============
Id (pk),
UnitId (fk),
UserId (fk),
ManagerType int
```

For a specific UnitId I need to find the closest (upwards) unit that has at least one manager with ManagerType=2. Each unit can have several managers of each type and I need all managers for the closest unit.

1. If specified unit has managers with ManagerType=2, return the managers
2. Else if parent unit has the managers, return them
3. Else if parents parent unit has the managers, return them
4. If no unit in the tree has any managers of the right type, return nothing

I guess a CTE is the way to go but I need some help to build the query, thanks!

### Update:

Ok I´ve almost managed to complete the query thanks to Zohar Peled

```
with cte as
 (
    select Id, ParentId, Name, 0 as Depth
    from Unit
    where Id = @unitId

    union all

    select t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Name, c.Depth + 1
    from cte c
    inner join Unit t
    on t.Id = c.ParentId
)
select *
    from cte 
inner join UnitManager um 
    on cte.Id = um.UnitId 
where ManagerType = 2;
```

The above query will return all managers of type 2 for the specified unit and its parents (if any, only some units have managers): Ex:

```
Id (UnitId) Name        Depth    UserId ManagerType
===================================================
5           Sub unit x   1        4       2
5           Sub unit x   1        2       2
6           Sub unit y   3        1       2
6           Sub unit y   3        3       2
1           Main unit    6        1       2
```

In this example Sub unit x and y each have two managers Main unit has one.

The remaining problem is that I need to return only the rows with the lowest Depth-value, in this case the first two rows (Depth=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The way to handle recursion in sql server is with a recursive cte.

Create and populate sample tables (Please, in your next question save us this step):

```
DECLARE @UnitManager as table
(
    UnitId int,
    ManagerType int
)

DECLARE @Unit as table
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    ParentId int null,
    Name char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @UnitManager 
VALUES (2, 2), (4, 1)

INSERT INTO @Unit 
VALUES (NULL, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (NULL, 'Z'), (4, 'Y')
```

The recursice CTE:

```
DECLARE @UnitId int = 3

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name
    FROM @Unit 
    WHERE Id = @UnitId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.Id, T.ParentId, T.Name
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN @Unit T
    ON T.Id = C.ParentId
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN 
@UnitManager M ON CTE.Id = M.UnitId 
WHERE ManagerType = 2
ORDER BY UnitId DESC
```

Results:

```
Id          ParentId    Name UnitId      ManagerType
----------- ----------- ---- ----------- -----------
2           1           B    2           2
```

For `@UnitId int = 5`, where there is no manager of type 2 up the ladder, the result is an empty recordset.

**Update**

Well, it might not be the best way to do it, but this will get you the results you want:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, 0 as rowNum
    FROM @Unit 
    WHERE Id = @UnitId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.Id, T.ParentId, T.Name, rowNum + 1 as rowNum
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN @Unit T
    ON T.Id = C.ParentId
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, ManagerType, rowNum
    FROM CTE 
    INNER JOIN 
    @UnitManager M ON CTE.Id = M.UnitId 
    WHERE ManagerType = 2
)
SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, ManagerType, rowNum
FROM CTE2 
WHERE rowNum = (SELECT MIN(rowNum) FROM CTE2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I will supply tables next time!
Looks good but it only returns one manager, it´s possible for a Unit to have several managers. And about the "ORDER BY UnitId DESC" in the last query; I may be wrong here but there is no guarantee that a child has a higher id than its parent.

So the desired result should be all Managers of type 2 from the closest Unit (starting at specified id and moving upwards).

I guess maybe one could also include the current depth (reversed) (starting at 0) and then in the last query select all Managers that have the lowest depth-value?

Comment: I will probably not have the time to edit my answer until sunday. I'll try to remember this then.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with my current query after the changes